# Number of ways to split Binary Necklace

Tags: combinatorics

It is known that a necklace made of two color beads (say $2a$ black ones and $2b$ white ones) can be split into equal portions by two cuts. My question is that given some configuration of such a necklace, how many different fair splits can one have?

Is it related to the necklace counting problem, i.e. maybe the number of ways depends on the size of each necklace equivalence class?

Clearly, if the configuration has a cyclic symmetry $C_n$(n as large as possible), then the answer is $1$ if $n$ is odd, and $2(a+b)/n$ if $n$ is even. However, when there is no cyclic symmetry, it seems one can have many possibilities, and the answer is not so obvious. Are there some results in combinatorics that are relevant?

Comment: You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my exercise, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: The answer obviously very much depends on the configuration, there can be just one as there can be half the amount of beads, so it's unclear what you are after.

Comment: @Shaun thanks for the suggestions

Comment: @ArnaudMortier just want to classify them if possible~

Comment: Much better. May be some of the initiated are already happy with this version? I would like to know more 1) about your *equivalence class*, are mirror images of necklaces in the same equivalence class? Apparently rotated versions are? 2) What is the meaning of a *maximal* symmetry? Is $n=a+b$ necessary for the group of symmetries to be called maximal? Are you excluding reflections as symmetries here?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Say excluding reflections for what I consider. By maximal I mean,  the necklace may have cyclic symmetry of $C_n$ for various $n$, and the result uses the max $n$ among them, the others just correspond to its subgroups.

Comment: Ok. Meanwhile, the others managed to reopen this already :-)